# Como obter o primary key de um item em uma recycleview ordenada

Tags: android

Eu tenho um recycleview populado com um banco Realm, se eu não ordenar, meu código funciona, pois ele coloca na ordem do ID ( primary key ). Porem eu quero ordenar por ordem alfabética, e quando faço isso meu código que é para abrir um dialog, não funciona pois a posição do click não é o mesmo do id.
Como eu posso pegar o id quando clicar ?

```
   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    adapter = new MeuAdpaterAlimentos(realm.where(Alimento.class).findAll(),true,true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            Alimento alimento = realm.where(Alimento.class).equalTo("id",position).findFirst();
            //Log.d(TAG, "onItemClicked: "+ v.toString());
            criarnumberpickdialog(alimento.getMedida(),alimento.getNome(),alimento.getCarboidratos(),alimento.getCalorias(),alimento.getGordura(),alimento.getProteinas());
        }
    });
```

Meu Adpater:

```
package com.igoroliv.lifestyle.Telas.Alimentacao;


import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.igoroliv.lifestyle.Modelos.Alimento;
import com.igoroliv.lifestyle.R;

import io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection;
import io.realm.RealmRecyclerViewAdapter;

/**
 * Created by igord on 21/11/2017.
 */

class MeuAdpaterAlimentos extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Alimento,MeuAdpaterAlimentos.VH> {

    public MeuAdpaterAlimentos(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Alimento> data, boolean autoUpdate, boolean updateOnModification) {
        super(data, autoUpdate, updateOnModification);
    }


    @Override
    public VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.linharecyclealimento, parent, false);
        return new VH(itemView);    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
        final Alimento alimento = getItem(position);
        //holder.data = alimento;
        holder.titulo.setText(alimento.getNome());

        String str = alimento.getMedida();
        String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : strArray) {
            String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
            builder.append(cap + " ");
        }
        holder.medida.setText(builder.toString());
    }


    public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //public Alimento data;
        TextView titulo,medida;


        public VH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titulo =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_alimentonome);
            medida =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txv_alimentoMedida);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como o `MeuAdpaterAlimentos` foi implementado?

Comment: @LeonardoLima editei e acrescentei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementente o getItemId do adapter, retornando o id do seu objeto. Exemplo:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return alimentos.get(position).getId();
}
```

Porém, isso vai funcionar somente se ordenar a lista base do adapter também.

Comment: Funcionou, mas tive que fazer assim:
        alimento = getItem(position);
        return alimento.getId();

Comment: É porque a lista eu sempre trabalho com ela global, mas se funcionou ta blz.